# Bootstrap customize carousel blurry thumbnail

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I wanted to make it clear as you can see on the picture thumbnail is too blurry i just wanted to make it a clear image. and the arrow on the thumbnails are to close to the end picture.

```
<div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:0px !important;">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
              <img src="" class="crsl-img">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/00ffff/000&amp;text=Product+Image+2" class="crsl-img">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ff00ff/fff&amp;text=Product+Image+3" class="crsl-img">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/ffff00/000&amp;text=Product+Image+4" class="crsl-img">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/612b65/fff&amp;text=Product+Image+5" class="crsl-img">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/00ffff/000&amp;text=Product+Image+6" class="crsl-img">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/db371b/fff&amp;text=Product+Image+7" class="crsl-img">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/feb8aa/000&amp;text=Product+Image+8" class="crsl-img">
          </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
  </div>
</div><!-- end col-md-12 -->
```

Comment: Whats your question and code?

Comment: ok thnx for the info sir. i will wait for a while

Comment: The only thing we can do with your code is a simple carousel.... http://www.bootply.com/oKc8SeBvJp

Comment: wait for awhile sir i didn't know how to use jsfiddle its my first time sorry

Comment: here is the code for thumbnails sir http://www.bootply.com/vM4kWD7nR6

Comment: But the image are generated by a third party website.... I think you can't do something.... Maybe should you send an issue to placehold.it .....